# Flutter – How to change appbar's selected icon onpressed and deselect it automatically when another icon is selected?

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter. I have an appbar with 5 IconButton. I want to change the icon of the IconButton and its color when pressed, and automatically undo the changes when another IconButton is pressed. Help me please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

first, create a List boolean to store the state of icons

false = deselected , true = selected

```
 List<bool> isPressed = [false, false, false, false, false];
```

create a function to set the list to the initial value

```
  getInitial() {
    List<bool> isPressed = [false, false, false, false, false];
    return isPressed;
  }
```

whenever you tap on the icon :

1. `isPressed = getInitial();`  // set the list to initial values so that all the icons will be reset to default colour.
2. `isPressed[index] = true;`  //the setthe specific index to true so that specific icon will change the colour

here is the implementation code: hope you got it

```dart
       AppBar(
             title: const Text("hello world"),
             actions: [
               GestureDetector(
                 onTap: () {
                   setState(() {
                     if (isPressed[0] == false) {
                       isPressed = getInitial();
                       isPressed[0] = true;
                     } else
                       isPressed[0] = false;
                   });
                 },
                 child: Icon(
                   Icons.favorite,
                   color: isPressed[0] == false ? Colors.white : Colors.red,
                 ),
               ),
               GestureDetector(
                 onTap: () {
                   setState(() {
                     if (isPressed[1] == false) {
                       isPressed = getInitial();
                       isPressed[1] = true;
                     } else
                       isPressed[1] = false;
                   });
                 },
                 child: Icon(
                   Icons.favorite,
                   color: isPressed[1] == false ? Colors.white : Colors.red,
                 ),
               )
             ],
           ),
```